# Parse image from web json

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
{
    "adTitle": "My Title",
    "adURL": "https://mylink.com/",
    "adImageURL": "http://mywebsite/bannerx@3x.png"
}
```

I get the JSON value from website: http://mywebsite.com/file.json

The problem is that the ad somehow doesn't load the adImageURL, so when I press the `UIImageView`, but when I press the area that then `UIImageView` should be, it open my adURL. This is the code I use for JSON:

```
var imageURL:String = "http://mywebsite/bannerx@3x.png"
    var adURL:String = "https://mylink.com/"

    func loadAdvertisement() {

        // Set up the URL request
        let todoEndpoint: String = "http://mywebsite.com/file.json"

        guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                // print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
                // print(error!)
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]) != nil else {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]


                if (json != nil) {

                    self.imageURL = (json["adImageURL"] as? String)!
                    self.adURL = (json["adURL"] as? String)!

                    print(self.imageURL)
                    print(self.adURL)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in

                        self.loadAdImage(self.imageURL)
                    }

                }


            } catch  {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }
        }

        task.resume()

        // let jsonURL = URL(string: "http://mywebsite.com/file.json")

        // self.getDataFromUrl(jsonURL!, completion: (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?)) -> Void


    }

    func loadAdImage(_ url:String) {

        getDataFromUrl(URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error)  in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
                print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "")
                print("Download Finished")
                self.advertImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }

    func getDataFromUrl(_ url:URL, completion: @escaping ((_ data: Data?, _ response: URLResponse?, _ error: NSError? ) -> Void)) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in

            completion(data, response, error as NSError?)


        }.resume()

    }
```

In the event LOG, is prints out both of the `print("error trying to convert data to JSON")` commands. I have used this code before in my project, and it worked just fine, but I have no idea why it wont work anymore.

Comment: Try catching the error that is thrown by `jsonObject(with:options:)`, it should tell you what's wrong with the JSON data.

Comment: @dr_barto - I get error message: ´error trying to convert data to JSONError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 180." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 180.} error trying to convert data to JSONError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 180." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 180.}´

Comment: Well, sounds like a reason to me :) The server sends malformed JSON, so print it out to see what's wrong with it...

Comment: @dr_barto Print it out from where exactly?

Comment: Convert `responseData` to a string, e.g. as described here: https://gist.github.com/Edudjr/cbd09220de89679f25eced359a6b8e08

Comment: @dr_barto This is so weird. The code works just fine on a new project, but in my existing project it wont work at all... I have no idea what the problem might be..

Comment: Check the response JSON with jsonlint.com or something similar, this will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @dr_barto But the exact same code works just fine on the new project, I have just code/paste the same code to the new project file, so it makes noe sense at all. Can there be any settings blocking or something?

Comment: @dr_barto The jsonlint.com gave me output: ´Valid JSON´

Comment: Have you checked what's "around character 180" in your JSON (from the not-pretty-printed string, i.e. without `.prettyPrinted` option)?

Comment: @dr_barto This is interesting. I deleted the ´App Transport Security Settings´ and added again, now it all works fine in my main project. Makes no sense at all, but after all - it works now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the message to catch and check what actually error you are getting like this way:

```
 do {

        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]        

    } catch let message  {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON" + "\(message)")
        return
    }
```

Comment: This is the error message I get in the event log: `error trying to convert data to JSONError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 180." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 180.}
error trying to convert data to JSONError Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 180." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 180.}
`

Comment: @CannonCen You are getting malformed JSON, Your need to check your server response.